# ExpressionMapper : Cannot achieve lambda mapping in specific scenario

Tags: lambda, expression, automapper

I'm a happy new user of ExpressionMapper, but i'm stuck with this specific scenario.

```cs
    public class TestExpressionMapper
    {
        private static IMapper _mapper;

        static void Main()
        {
            #region Populate test

            List<EmployeeEntity> empEntity = new List<EmployeeEntity>
            {
                new EmployeeEntity { Id = 1, Name = "Jean-Louis", Age = 39, Events = new EventEntity[]{ new EventEntity { EventType = "Start", EventDate = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1) } }.ToList() },
                new EmployeeEntity { Id = 2, Name = "Jean-Paul", Age = 32, Events = new EventEntity[]{ new EventEntity { EventType = "Start", EventDate = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-2) } }.ToList() },
                new EmployeeEntity { Id = 3, Name = "Jean-Christophe", Age = 19, Events = new EventEntity[]{ new EventEntity { EventType = "Start", EventDate = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1) } }.ToList() },
                new EmployeeEntity { Id = 4, Name = "Jean-Marie", Age = 27, Events = new EventEntity[]{ new EventEntity { EventType = "Start", EventDate = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-3) } }.ToList() },
                new EmployeeEntity { Id = 5, Name = "Jean-Marc", Age = 22, Events = new EventEntity[]{ new EventEntity { EventType = "Start", EventDate = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-5) } }.ToList() },
                new EmployeeEntity { Id = 5, Name = "Jean-Pierre", Age = 22, Events = new EventEntity[]{ new EventEntity { EventType = "Start", EventDate = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-5) } }.ToList() },
                new EmployeeEntity { Id = 6, Name = "Christophe", Age = 55, Events = new EventEntity[]{ new EventEntity { EventType = "Start", EventDate = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1) } }.ToList() },
                new EmployeeEntity { Id = 7, Name = "Marc", Age = 23, Events = new EventEntity[]{ new EventEntity { EventType = "Start", EventDate = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-2) } }.ToList() },
                new EmployeeEntity { Id = 8, Name = "Paul", Age = 38, Events = new EventEntity[]{ new EventEntity { EventType = "Start", EventDate = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-10) }, new EventEntity { EventType = "Stop", EventDate = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1) } }.ToList() },
                new EmployeeEntity { Id = 8, Name = "Jean", Age = 32, Events = new EventEntity[]{ new EventEntity { EventType = "Start", EventDate = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-10) }, new EventEntity { EventType = "Stop", EventDate = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-2) } }.ToList() },
            };

            #endregion

            #region Mapping config

            _mapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<EmployeeModel, EmployeeEntity>().ReverseMap();
                cfg.CreateMap<EventModel, EventEntity>().ReverseMap();
            }).CreateMapper();

            _mapper.ConfigurationProvider.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

            #endregion

            #region Test

            Expression<Func<EmployeeModel, bool>> filter;
            Expression<Func<EmployeeEntity, bool>> mappedFilter;

            // Works : Returns employees whose name starts with "Jean"
            filter = emp => emp.Name.StartsWith("Jean");
            mappedFilter = _mapper.MapExpression<Expression<Func<EmployeeEntity, bool>>>(filter);
            var res1 = empEntity.AsQueryable().Where(mappedFilter);

            //Works : Returns employees having at least one "Stop" event
            filter = emp => emp.Events.Any(evt => evt.EventType.Equals("Stop"));
            mappedFilter = _mapper.MapExpression<Expression<Func<EmployeeEntity, bool>>>(filter);
            var res2 = empEntity.AsQueryable().Where(mappedFilter);

            //Works : Returns employees having any event older than 3 years
            filter = emp => emp.Events.Any(evt => evt.EventDate < DateTime.Today.AddYears(-3));
            mappedFilter = _mapper.MapExpression<Expression<Func<EmployeeEntity, bool>>>(filter);
            var res3 = empEntity.AsQueryable().Where(mappedFilter);

            //Works : Returns employees having a stop event older than 1 year (no expression mapping -> lambda is built against entities)
            mappedFilter = emp =>
                emp.Events.Any(e => e.EventType.Equals("Stop")) &&
                emp.Events.First(e => e.EventType.Equals("Stop")).EventDate < DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1);
            var res4 = empEntity.AsQueryable().Where(mappedFilter);

            //Breaks on mapping : Same lambda as previous one but built against models then mapped
            filter = emp =>
                emp.Events.Any(e => e.EventType.Equals("Stop")) &&
                emp.Events.First(e => e.EventType.Equals("Stop")).EventDate < DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1);
            mappedFilter = _mapper.MapExpression<Expression<Func<EmployeeEntity, bool>>>(filter);
            var res5 = empEntity.AsQueryable().Where(mappedFilter);

            #endregion

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }

    internal class EmployeeEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public List<EventEntity> Events { get; set; }
    }

    internal class EventEntity
    {
        public string EventType { get; set; }
        public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }
    }


    internal class EmployeeModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public List<EventModel> Events { get; set; }
    }

    internal class EventModel
    {
        public string EventType { get; set; }
        public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }
    }
```

In the last mapping I have an ArgumentException saying "Property 'System.DateTime EventDate' is not defined for Type TestExpressionMapper.EventEntity" which is obviously wrong since the property exists.
Is there any mistake inmy code or is it a non-covered scenario in ExpressionMapper ? If so, is there any workaround ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in ExpressionMapper. 
Using a version >= 3.0.2-preview01 solved the problem.

See [Github issue](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.ExpressionMapping/issues/41)